# OperationalError no such table in Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask

run.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config() 
    app.run()
```

main.py

```
import database

app = Flask(__name__)

def config():
    app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')

    # Run SQLAlchemy _that uses app.config_ and add entities if in DEBUG mode
    database.init_db(app)

    import blueprints.auth
    app.register_blueprint(blueprints.auth.auth)
```

database.py

```
db = None

def init_db(app):
    global db
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    from models import User, Interest, Event

    if app.config['DEBUG']:
        print 'Recreating all db'
        db.create_all() # I DO create everything
        print 'Loading test data'
        ... (here I add some Users and etc. and everything works fine - tests pass)
```

models.py

```
from database import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
...
```

blueprints/auth.py

```
from models import User

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/')
def index():
    return str(User.query.get(1).interests)
```

And so I get

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: user u'SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.passhash AS user_passhash, user.vk_page AS user_vk_page \nFROM user \nWHERE user.id = ?' (1,)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did the table `user` actually end up being created in the database? Have you checked with another program?

Comment: `db.create_all()` is only executed in debug mode. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone trying to use an in memory database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool

engine = create_engine(
    "sqlite://", 
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}, 
    poolclass=StaticPool
)
```

Comment: You're the man. This is I think the actual answer for having an in memory DB, instead of just switching to a file.

Comment: Oh my god, you're the guy. `poolclass=StaticPool` made the difference for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

There were few things I had to change to make everything work.

1. replace `DATABASE_URI` with `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` parametr in config
2. replace `:memory:` sqlite address with `/tmp/test.db`

Now it works fine.

Comment: +1000 ... geez, that was frustrating. `db.create_all()` is $@#&*^#* with in-memory sqlite ... ok ...

Comment: Explanation for this behavior: http://gehrcke.de/2015/05/in-memory-sqlite-database-and-flask-a-threading-trap/

Comment: I understand how to complete the first part of the this answer, but I'm not sure what you mean by the second part. I assume the `:memory:` address needs set equal to `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, but I am not sure how to do that. What do I need to append to my `config.py` file?

Comment: @sudosensei it just means, don't use in-memory storage :) if you used `:memory:`before, don't. If you did not, you are good.

Comment: My issue was actually something different altogether. Thank you for the quick reply though!